# Android: How to change main view background from PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, background, sharedpreferences, preferenceactivity

i have a preferenceScreen with the option to change background of the main_layout. I tried to create another activity to do the job but it doesn't work at all.
For now i only can change from the main_view, using buttons.
When i try this in the setOnPreferenceClickListener:

```
View view=(View) findViewByid(R.id.main_layout);
view.setBackgroundDrawable(draw);
```

i got this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/1 }} to activity {com.helloworld/com.helloworld.Preferences}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

How can i change the background from my preferenceScreen and how to save it?

Comment: i search some more and now i'm using intents. But still no luck.